# Is there a way not to generate controller specs by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I'm a fan of Rspec, but I never use either controller or view specs. I know the following options exist:

```
Usage:
  rails generate controller NAME [action action] [options]

Rspec options:
  [--controller-specs], [--no-controller-specs]  # Indicates when to generate controller specs
                                                 # Default: true
  [--view-specs], [--no-view-specs]              # Indicates when to generate view specs
                                                 # Default: true
```

But is there a way for Rspec to skip on generating these by default? I don't want to be typing `--no-controller-specs --no-view-specs` every time I generate a controller for instance.

**How can I disable spec generation by default?** (while keeping some others, eg. models)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can configure it in `application.rb` like this:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec,
    fixtures: true,
    view_specs: false,
    helper_specs: true,
    routing_specs: false,
    controller_specs: false,
    request_specs: true
end
```